# Which features should I look at when choosing typefaces for classical, text-rich publications?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, book

I am thinking about self-publishing some of Søren Kierkegaard's works (mainly because I realised that I can release them at a much cheaper price than what they currently cost). In order to keep costs down,  I am looking for some good **free** font(s) that would work well in this context. I have (more or less) decided upon a size of 13.5 cm x 21.5 cm (approximately the same as 6 in x 9 in), font size 10pt. The number of pages varies between 100 and 300 pages, but in order to keep costs down, I keep the top and bottom margins small (probably around 0.72 in and 0.65 in, respectively). I am using running headers in the top margins.

**Any good recommendations?** I know, I know: It depends on taste. The problem is, I do not trust my own taste on this. I need advice from someone with more experience than myself. **Any particular features to look for in typefaces for these kinds of works?** Any advice, anything at all, is appreciated.

*By the way:* There is a lot of Greek text in these works, so the fonts need to support this well.

Answer (score 1):

[Gentium](http://www.sil.org/resources/software_fonts/gentium) from SIL will likely work well for a free font. The SIL Open Font license also means that you can edit the font for your own needs using a font editor like [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/). Gentium was designed for scholarly work and supports Latin, Cyrillic, and Greek.

[image: Gentium screenshot]
[image: Gentium Greek characters]

Comment: @DumbNic - I've added screenshots of both the Latin and Greek characters. As for why it works well, I thought my line of , "Gentium was designed for scholarly work and supports Latin, Cyrillic, and Greek" was a pretty fair summation of why it would work well for this particular use case.

Answer (score 1):

I can't recommend a font but I would consider fonts that were available up to the 1850s, or at most up to the beginning of the 20th C.

So, maybe some modern romans. I don't really see the Arts and Crafts movement working that well for today's audience but ... it might.

The UX guy in me says - know your audience.